# TypeOrm & MongoDB: Column aliases ignored on insert/save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, orm, typeorm

When using column aliases with MongoDB, TypeORM does not use the alias (Column name) when inserting/updating records, it only uses it when querying data.

### Expected Behavior

When declaring a class like this

```js
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
   @ObjectIdColumn() readonly id: ObjectID;
   @Column({ name: "first_name" }) firstName: string;
}
```

and inserting a new record with a MongoRepository like this

```js
const newUser = this.usersRepository.create({ firstName: 'Joe' });
return await this.usersRepository.save(newUser);
```

I expect the fields in then record in the database to be snake case not camel case

### Actual Behavior

`firstName` column is not mapped to `first_name`

### Steps to Reproduce

Create an entity like the following and use the type orm MongoRepository to save a new record.

```js
@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
   @ObjectIdColumn() readonly id: ObjectID;
   @Column({ name: "first_name" }) firstName: string;
}
```

### Environment

| Dependency | Version |
| --- | --- |
| OS | Windows 10 |
| NodeJs | 16.6.2 |
| TypeORM | 0.2.37 |
| MongoDB | 4.2 |

[Crossposted from Github Issues](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7620)